# What is the proper value type of the new value when using ini_set()?

Tags: php, ini

I will use "display_errors" as an example:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);// int
ini_set('display_errors', '1');// string
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');// string
ini_set('display_errors', true);// boolean
```

I know that all the above will work the same. I'm just curious to know what's the **most proper** one to use, if anyone knows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring : http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php

```
string ini_set ( string $varname , string $newvalue )
```

So you have to use a string for newValue

eg:

```
<?php
echo ini_get('display_errors');

if (!ini_get('display_errors')) {
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
}

echo ini_get('display_errors');
?>
```

Comment: Since the default value of ini_get() before changing anything are `string (1)`, I think you're answer is better. Even http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php has default values to '0' or '1' !!

Answer (score 5):

On php.net the syntax looks like this:

> string ini_set(string $varname, string $newvalue)

All parameters should be a `string`. On the php.ini file all booleans shown as `On` or `Off`. The following solution should be the most proper solution:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');
```

On the documentation of the configuration file you can find the following part:

> Boolean values can be set to either:
>     true, on, yes
>     **or** false, off, no, none

http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php

On `ini_get` the return value is a string. The documentation says:

> A boolean ini value of off will be returned as an empty string or "0" while a boolean ini value of on will be returned as "1". The function can also return the literal string of INI value.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php

The return value of `ini_get` and the value for `ini_set` have to be a string!

Comment: In configuration.file.php, I find it strange that 1 and 0 are not mentioned! Maybe 1 and 0 are invalid inside php.ini !?

Comment: These values also works but the original values are these from documentation.

Comment: also weird, the default values when using `ini_get('display_errors')` are string '0' or string '1' !

Comment: You can use both! You have to declare a proper solution for youself. If ini_get return '0' and '1', use '0' and '1' for ini_set too, but ini_get can also return literal string of INI value!

Answer (score 0):

It must be same as you set it in php.ini file. From documentation:

`string ini_set ( string $varname , string $newvalue )`

So it means you can use any string for `$newvalue` and that will be *most proper* way. But usually I set it to `(int) 1`